# Facebook client that shows whole message history

Tags: software-recommendation, facebook

I tried many Facebook clients but I still miss one specific feature: showing all messages. Both Thunderbird and Pidgin show all messages I sent over this client but not the other messages. Does anybody know such a client or an additional plugin for this task? Is is possible to download Facebook messages?